# C# setting cookie using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, nshttpcookie

I'm using a test automation platform called Ranorex. The code is C#. I would like to set a cookie to the server using HttpWebRequest before I open a browser to begin the test.

Below is the code. Everything executes with no problem. When I view the cookies using the browser - mine is not there (there are 54 other cookies) - when I iterate the response as shown below - I only have three (3) cookies.

Your help is appreciated.

This method will execute the test

```
void ITestModule.Run()
{

  SummaryHelper.KillAllInternetExplorerProcesses(); 

  uri = this.createURI();

  // Using HttpWebRequest to set a cookie to the session
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

  request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();            

  Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("mockFlagForTesting", "true", "/", "safeqa.thomson.com");

  request.CookieContainer.Add(myCookie);    


  // Create the processStartInfo obejct to open the IE Browser
  // I expect the cookie to be loaded into the session
  ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
    @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");

  processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
  processStartInfo.Arguments = uri;
  SummaryBase.process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

  // Create and set a session cookie. 
  setHTTPCookie();
}



private void setHTTPCookie()
{

  // We will attempt to set the cookie here 
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

  request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();  

  Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("mockFlagForTesting", "true", "/", "safeqa.thomson.com");

  // Add the cookie
  request.CookieContainer.Add(myCookie); 

  // Do we need to use POST here to write to the server ?? 
  // Set the request.Method using WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

  // Iterate the cookies
  // We only display three (3) ?? 
  foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
  {
    Report.Info("-------------------------------------------------------------");
    Report.Info("cook.Name", cook.Name);
    Report.Info("cook.Value", cook.Value);
    Report.Info("Domain: ", cook.Domain);
    Report.Info("Path: ", cook.Path);
  }            

  response.Close();   
}
```

Thanks 
Chris

Comment: have you looked at examples on how to create a cookie using `HttpCookie` something looks off about how you are creating your `myCookie` object

Comment: Yes, why would you expect otherwise? There is no connection between you making web request and browser making web request (i.e. would you expect to see my cookies if I made request to the server?)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are confused. You are setting the cookie in your HttpWebRequest, but that is in no way connected to Internet Explorer.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new at this Http stuff. It seems I should be able to use HttpWebRequest and/or HttpWebResponse AND my uri (the connection between the request and the IE session (maybe)) to write a cookie to the server that will get loaded into the browser ??? in C# :--) Most of the samples on microsoft (thanks DJ KRAZE) are focused on ASP and assume you are working in a browser session - I'm running a executable ... again - any comments are welcome. I'll keep researching - there are some smart guys on the 6h floor I'll go and talk to :--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set cookie in browser, not on some random web request.

You can either push cookies via script running on the page OR inject cookies to request if you can intercept requests (i.e. using Fiddler/ Fiddler Core).